# Create boundary area in Google Maps using coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show an area boundary in Google maps using API v3. I've got a list of postcodes for the area that the client covers, I've converted these to LatLng coordinates and can create a polygon with them but as you would expect, it's a mess of lines and not a solid shape area.

Anyone know if this is possible and if so, how to do this? Or a different way of doing this. Code I'm using below:

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 55.921772, lng: -3.383983},
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            streetViewControl: true
            });

        // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
        var triangleCoords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.948969,-3.1927988),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.949292,-3.209399),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.957032,-3.1850223),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.929196,-3.2089489),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.934519,-3.2131166),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.924534,-3.2096679),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.901564,-3.2035307),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.940591,-3.2170048),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.943847,-3.2184679),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.932823,-3.2462462),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.924084,-3.2938003),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.948636,-3.3239403),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.94727,-3.2158532),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.946459,-3.2359557),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.942119,-3.2790791),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.943678,-3.2820926),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.933458,-3.2867013),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.907231,-3.2498242),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.914285,-3.2391396),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.929872,-3.2483283),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.919613,-3.272673),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.913635,-3.2773089),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.953223,-3.1155757),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.951535,-3.1124523),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.944854,-3.1050555),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.931274,-3.1456767),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.938277,-3.1758846),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.919988,-3.1677619),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.907921,-3.1339982),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.899518,-3.1649876),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.955011,-3.1932569),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.953699,-3.1905739),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.951683,-3.2010498),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.951121,-3.2034185),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.877027,-3.1487295),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.943146,-3.0559971),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.943718,-3.047895),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.939247,-3.0130501),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.892996,-3.0728633),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.89186,-3.0692661),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.892996,-3.0728633),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.956248,-3.4049741),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.958401,-3.204173),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.953391,-3.2083257),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.947542,-3.2146128),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.943346,-3.2109749),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.945203,-3.2049162),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.973614,-3.3522429),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.959293,-2.9831886),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.958761,-3.2259363),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.958258,-3.2509238),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.954508,-3.2162083),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.969754,-3.2567425),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.965345,-3.2713865),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.966799,-3.2759201),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.961259,-3.2624101),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.960523,-3.3189479),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.980282,-3.2222259),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.970837,-3.2150703),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.972055,-3.1971305),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.977169,-3.1812151),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.970188,-3.1726547),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.970989,-3.1715573),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.9706,-3.1709047),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.969318,-3.1629671),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.958457,-3.1835442),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.954315,-3.1853397),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.956023,-3.1607265),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.955162,-3.15005),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.950521,-3.1836543),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.94698,-3.1866047),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.934593,-3.1935895),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.934464,-3.1948181),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.930516,-3.1756174),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.97862,-3.2535203),
        new google.maps.LatLng(55.951962,-3.1749222)
        ];


        // Construct the polygon.
        var areaCovered = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: triangleCoords,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.25
        });
        areaCovered.setMap(map);


    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What I would do is create a LatLngBounds from all your coordinates and then create a polygon from the NSEW corners of the bounds. You'll end up with a big rectangle that contains all your coordinates. When I have more time later today I'll give you a code example.

Comment: Thanks @tmentink that sounds like the kind of thing I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here is that code example I promised. This will give you a square/rectangle polygon that contains all the points in triangleCoords.

```
// create new LatLngBounds
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// extend bounds to contain each coordinate
for (var i = 0, i_end = triangleCoords.length; i < i_end; i++) {
    bounds.extend(triangleCoords[i]);
}

// get the NSEW corners of the bounds
var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();
var SE = { lat: SW.lat(), lng: NE.lng() };
var NW = { lat: NE.lat(), lng: SW.lng() };

// Construct the polygon.
var areaCovered = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [NE, SE, SW, NW],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.25
});
areaCovered.setMap(map);
```

I also wanted to clarify why your code was creating a mess of lines. A polygon will construct its boundary based on the order of the coordinates you supply it. To get an idea of what I'm talking about you can change the order in my example to this `paths: [NE, SW, SE, NW]`.

To give you a visual, you can think of it like the game of connect the dots. If you didn't connect these dots in order you would end up with a *mess of lines* instead of a cute laughing Pikachu.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect and just what I need thanks @tmentink. Do you know if there is there a way centre the map on the centre of polygon bound and resize/zoom the area so it can be fully seen on smaller screens or as you resize your browser?

Comment: @fsylothian You are looking for the `fitBounds()` method. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map). If you found this answer helpful I would appreciate it if you marked it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, the Polygon have NOT to be closed.

Bevor Edit:
Your Polygon have to be closed.
As in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes , where i think you get your source from, the last and the first point are the same.

Comment: Hi Peter. tried that and it doesn't matter if Polygon is closed or not.